# Can I make Javascript inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I will make javascript inside javascript like this code.

```
<p id="div"></p>
<p id="jancuk"></p>

<script>
  document.getElementById("jancuk").innerHTML = '<script 
  src="encryption.js" type="text/javascript">' + '</script>';
</script>
<script>
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "text show"; </script>
```

Code can't work correctly. 
I will include data javascript 1 to javascript 2. it's mean wrapper inside one html document. 
Please help me if you know about this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204970/discussion-on-question-by-cak-sup-can-i-make-javascript-inside-javascript).